# how does node create UTXO from blockchain for the first time?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, blockchain, bitcoind, utxo

Let's say I am a new node.

I try to synch with the full node to grab the whole blockchain. Now, I synced with it .It's time for my node to create UTXO database ..

How does it do this exactly so that it knows which one to put in UTXO database ? since it will need to know which one is unspent. By looking at the blockchain, it can't quickly figure out which one is unspent for the following Reason: 1st height block contains output which has 5btc sent to me. I only spend this in the 400,000th block. This kind of thing happens for every other output. So how does bitcoin build UTXO in an effective way ?

It would also be great if there could be any code from bitcoind or something so i can take a look. Couldn't find it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UTXO set is updated every time a block is connected to the chain. So if you imagine during initial sync, you download block #1 and verify it, then add one UTXO to the database (the coinbase output). Block #2 gets downloaded and verified, and you add one more UTXO to the set and so on. Eventually you download block #1000 which contains a transaction that spends the coinbase output from block #1. If everything is valid, you delete that block #1 coinbase output from the UTXO set and replace it with whatever new coins are created by the transaction in block #1000.

So your assumption that "Now, I synced with it. It's time for my node to create UTXO database" is incorrect - the UTXO database is always under constant maintenance from the moment you launch bitcoind.

To start digging through the code, note [this call to `UpdateCoins()` in the function `ConnectBlock()`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/12a1c3ad1a43634d2a98717e49e3f02c4acea2fe/src/validation.cpp#L2193). This will eventually call [`AddCoins()`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/12a1c3ad1a43634d2a98717e49e3f02c4acea2fe/src/coins.cpp#L102) and you can see the UTXO are actually added to a cache first (which is eventually flushed to disk). But this is the mechanism you are looking for.

You can see where coins are removed from the UTXO cache in [`SpendCoin()`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/12a1c3ad1a43634d2a98717e49e3f02c4acea2fe/src/coins.cpp#L113)

Comment: so let's say utxo database is key value and keys are txid+vout. node checks txid+vout in inputs and if it's present in utxo , then it removes it from utxo. something like this ?

Comment: yes, I added some links to code in the answer

Comment: Before I check the code ,quick question. how does node know if an input is coinbase transaction ?

Comment: coinbase tx can be identified because their inputs are null (they "spend" from a txid of 32 `0x00` bytes) You can the function `isCoinbase()` in `transaction.h`

Comment: Thanks .  do nodes also try to download utxo sets from other nodes? because if i am a new node, syncing with other nodes might take lots of time(downloading blockchain, creating utxo) . does bitcoin do something like ethereum does ? downloading state trie and blockchain in parallel ?

Comment: That is not currently possible because there would be no way to verify the data is accurate. There have been several proposals to enable this however: search for "UTXO commitments" on this site.

Comment: Also check out: https://dci.mit.edu/utreexo